# How can I make the nastiest fingernails-on-blackboard type sound (not electronic)?

Tags: scratching

We all know how nasty the fingernails-on-a-blackboard sound is.

What can I do to make a sound of this kind which is as loud and nasty as possible?

This doesn't have to involve any particular materials, just any equipment that is typically found in a home or high school science lab. (It has to be portable and non-electronic.)

Comment: I kinda suspect a fingernails-on-blackboard sound isn't nasty at all unless the listener knows what it is. I.e., focus on making the _pictures_ as nasty as possible, not the sound.

Answer (score 1):

Fingernails are rather portable, and quite non-electronic.

Recording real nails on a real chalkboard, and then driving the most abrasive frequencies to near clipping would certainly have a stomach-churning effect.